# I am using windows XP on my pc. How can i increase brightness?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to increase brightness on you tube videos and movies. How do I do that?

Comment: I assume this means you have a laptop?  If you have the display drivers installed there should be a key on the keyboard that controls the setting of the internal display.

Comment: if you are using a desktop computer, it will be settings on the monitor, not the operating system. If it is a laptop, as Ramhound said, there should be a hotkey, provided the driver is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Movie mode as in youtube works a little differently from standard desktop mode, based on all my observations on various configurations.

I think the best approach to this is to adjust your brightness level from the video card driver.
If the driver has not too many specific options for various environments, use simply the RGB color adjustments and boost all 3 colors a little.